# App Removed From Facebook AppCenter

Tags: ios, facebook

How do you use SLRequest do detect if the Facebook user has disallowed the app by removing it from his AppCenter?  I had my app setup to allow posting to Facebook, but when I tested removing it from AppCenter, it messed up on me, and won't grant any permissions, or add it back to my AppCenter in Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

You probably used a faulty coding practice when you disallowed the use of Facebook.

Let's go ahead and assume that you used: `[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];` when you logged the user out of Facebook.

You need to have something like this in order for Facebook to be re-linked to your app. Resetting this way should ensure that you're never forgetting to re-initiate the session and token information.

```
- (void)createAndPresentLoginView
{
    if (self.loginViewController == nil) {
        self.loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController"
                                                                           bundle:nil];
        self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.loginViewController];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
    }
}
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I'm using SLRequest and not the Facebook sdk so there is no FBSession